# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

File "main.py", line 40, in 
**dp.loop.create_task(delay(30))**
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task'

```
async def delay(wait):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)

        now = datetime.utcnow()
        await bot.send_message(724700370, f"{now}", disable_notification=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(delay(30))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

```
bot = Bot(token=cfg.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(delay(10))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```